# How does one upgrade a trait card?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I recently unlocked the ["Scout" trait](http://battlefront.wikia.com/wiki/Scout) [star card](http://www.ign.com/wikis/star-wars-battlefront-next-gen/Star_Cards), and I noticed that it has 3 different levels with ever increasing effects.

> - **Level 1:** Sprinting does not show on enemy scanner.
> - **Level 2:** Sprinting and firing your primary weapon does not show on enemy scanner.
> - **Level 3**: Sprinting and firing your primary weapon does not show on enemy scanner and killing an enemy resets weapon heat.

[image: Scout Trait star card]
 Noticeably there doesn't appear to be a way to purchase the next level, so I assume that its a temporary leveling system.

**How does one upgrade [a trait](http://battlefront.wikia.com/wiki/Category:DICE_Traits) star card?**

The wikia entry for the [Sharpshooter trait](http://battlefront.wikia.com/wiki/Sharpshooter_trait) says:

> Level 1 is the predetermined level when someone appears on the
>   battlefield. The player gains one charge for every 3 kills (headshot
>   kills not necessary) without dying.

Is it the same for all trait cards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Traits are a special star card. You don't put this in your hand and
>   instead choose only one. These give kill streak rewards every 3 kills.
>   You start at level 1 every match and can go up to level 3. If you die,
>   you only go down one level. For example, if you are level 3 and die,
>   you go down to level 2. This way, you don't need to start from level 1
>   again.

On Your Second Link it says:

> Trait Cards are also unlockable and used as "Kill Streaks". Earning kills with these equipped cards will cause them to level up and buff the individual.

I believe this is straight forward. The wiki entry could be better phrased saying "...one level for..." instead of "charge"

[Source: "Star Wars Battlefront Star Cards and Traits Guide"](http://www.gameskinny.com/mt221/star-wars-battlefront-star-cards-and-traits-guide), *GameSkinny*